# GA4 events showing in debug, but not events list

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, conversion-tracking

I've read a few questions on this but nothing seems to have worked for me, I'd be grateful for any help.

Basically, events appear in the debug ribbon while in preview mode on GTM and I can see the debug parameter = 1.
When not in GTM preview mode and on the site normally, the events increase under 'top events' to the right of the debug ribbon, but don't appear in the ribbon itself.

At no point are these events available on the main events list to mark as conversions.

I've checked the GTM container is published, with events set up correctly and it's been a couple of weeks now.

I've tried changing the reporting identity from blended to observed.

I'm sure there are enough events happening for them to appear, as far as I can tell I've set this up exactly the same on other sites and it's worked fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Tom

Answer (score 0):

In the GA4 platform, unlike Universal Analytics, you need to wait 48/72 hours before seeing stable data in the reports.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say in my question, it's been much longer than this, a couple of weeks or so.

Comment: Same problem and only recently due to a GA4 upgrade. Any discoveries since your last post?